# 'A most' -- is it odd usage?

Tags: word-usage

Grammar books routinely insist on "the most" as for all superlatives, but I can recall certain cases where 'most' has not been used as '**the** superlative' but only as 'a superlative!'

(as in)

> Mr. Simpson said, "this is **a most** irregular way of writing this
>   sentence."
>
> He is **a most** brilliant exponent of the bamboo flute.
>
> But for her extreme lack of discipline, she is **a most** likeable
>   woman.

(tangential musing: how important is a comma, or its omission! Pl. compare these two constructions --

"but for her extreme lack of discipline,  she is a most likeable
woman"

"but, for her extreme lack of discipline, she is a most likeable
woman.")

Added after 15 minutes by edit:

I also recall seeing **least** and other superlatives being used similarly, as in

> She racked her mind for **a least** offensive word to describe his
>   vile deeds to his children.
>
> They looked for **an easiest** and **simplest** way to convince the old
>   person.
>
> Smoking was banned at the Simpsons' -- they considered it **a worst**
>   offence.

Grammatical giants at EL & U! Do you consider such cases odd usage? (or even downright **wrong**, I shouldn't be surprised!)

Comment: “but for her” means “except for her” or “apart from her” no comma should be used.

Comment: Two famous comma-significant examples: *A woman without her man is nothing* and Lynne Truss's *Eats shoots and leaves*  (http://theliterarylink.com/punc.html)

Comment: It’s not wrong.  It may be a bit dated-  This would be a typical idiom in conversation from a Jane Austin novel for example.

Comment: Now you’ve edited it and muddied the waters.

Comment: Very true -- the misplaced comma can change the whole meaning and even cause unintended offense in certain cases!

Comment: I have muddied the waters because dated but idiomatically sanctioned styles are not the only conditions where 'a' has been used with superlatives -- I would like to know whether such constructions can pass modern scrutiny in a variety of contexts.

Comment: Thanks to Mahmud Koya for formatting my question to highlight the examples. How can I do this myself?

Comment: The examples with _most_ aren’t superlatives—they’re adjectives in the positive degree modified by the adverb _most_, which in this context means ‘very’. All the other examples are completely ungrammatical to me. The superlative cannot be indefinite; it is by definition definite.

Comment: By the same logic, do you think **least** could also pass grammatical muster along with 'most' as in **it is a least inspiring personality trait** (where 'least inspiring' can be read as 'most uninspiring') and **in what way could I give her a least discouraging reply?**

Comment: ... Have you checked in a dictionary listing the intensifier usage of 'most' to see if it gives a corresponding usage for 'least'? Does 'I was feeling least peculiar' sound correct?

Comment: Thank you for directing me to the earlier question, which has some illuminating answers and comments.

Comment: You are right: 'least' certainly sounds more awkward than 'most' when used in this manner!

Comment: 1948 song:  "It's a Most Unusual Day"

Comment: The rule allowing 'a most' as modifier is now clear, but I cannot find any rule guidance regarding the use of 'a least' the same way as modifier. However it's logical to think that 'least' may also be used like 'most' -- it's time for someone to drag out an obscure and magical ruling for or against this admittedly odd usage!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definite article **the** is used with superlative adjectives when  a comparison takes place involving three or more persons or objects. In all other cases the superlative form **most** can act as a normal adjective, adverb, determiner, noun, pronoun etc. and can take **a/an, the** or **no article** as per the context.

**[Superlative adjectives](http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/comparative-and-superlative/)**

> Superlative adjectives are used to describe an object which is at the
> upper or lower limit of a quality (the tallest, the smallest, the
> fastest, the highest). They are used in sentences where a subject is
> compared to a group of objects.
>
> ***Noun (subject) + verb + the + superlative adjective + noun (object).***
>
> The group that is being compared with can be omitted if it is clear
> from the context (final example below). Examples
>
> *My house is **the largest** one in our neighborhood.*
>
> *This is **the smallest** box I've ever seen.*
>
> *Your dog ran **the fastest** of any dog in the race.*
>
> *We all threw our rocks at the same time. My rock flew **the
> highest**. ("of all the rocks" is understood)*

**[Most](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/most):** (thefreedictionary.com)

> **Adj** - Greatest in number: *won the **most** votes*
>
> In the greatest number of instances: ***Most** fish have fins.*
>
> **Noun** -  The greatest amount or degree: *She has the **most** to gain.*
>
> **Pronoun** -  (used with a sing. or pl. verb) The greatest part or number: ***Most** of the town was destroyed. **Most** of the books
> were missing.*
>
> **Adv** - 1. In or to the highest degree or extent. Used with many adjectives and adverbs to form the superlative degree: ***most**
> honest; **most** impatiently.*
>
> 2. Very: *a **most** impressive piece of writing.*
> 3. *Informal* Almost: ***Most** everyone agrees.*

Comment: Thank you -- you have given **a most** comprehensive and clear answer!